# Dictionary Search

Tags: php, mysql, c, algorithm

I have a dictionary(in form of sql table) containing model numbers of mobile phones and an article(or just a line) about mobiles phones(in form of a string in php or C). I want to find out the mobile phone models discussed in that article but I don't want to do a brute force search i.e. search each and every model name in the text one by one.

Also I was thinking of maintain a hash table of the entire dictionary and then try to match then against the hashes of each and every work in the article and look for the collisions. But since the dictionary is very large, memory overhead in this approach is too much.

Also, If there is no database at all i.e. we have everything in the language scope only, dictionary in form of array and text in form of string.

Comment: why you have "c" in the tags?

Comment: i know both C and php languages and looking for a solution in either of them.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely need to use FULLTEXT index on your article field and perform searches with MATCH/AGAINST for performing searches.

```
SELECT * FROM your_table MATCH('phonemodel') AGAINST ('article');
```

Comment: Is this approach efficient even in case if the string is small i.e. just a line.

Comment: Yes. MySql uses appropriate data structure for storing FULLTEXT index and search in such data structure is extremely efficient.

Comment: ok.. thats fine if i have every thing in the database itself and what about if there is no database. I am going to update the question as well.

Answer (score 1):

`Inverted index` would help. Link: [Inverted index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index)

Split your articles into tokens, filter tokens of model name. So you can build an index, the key of the index is model name, and the value of the index is an article list.

Maybe you can add some additional information like the position of model name appears in the article.

Answer (score 0):

If you thinking of using C and performance is what you wish for. I would suggest building a trie (**http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)** to all the words in the articles. It's a little faster than hashing and consumes much less memory than Dictionary.

It's not easy to implement in c, but I'm sure you can find one ready some where.

Good Luck (:

Answer (score 0):

If you have huge data then use one of them -

1. [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/)
2. [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/)

Trie/DAWG(Directed Acyclic Word Graph) are elegant solutions but also hard to implement & maintain. And, MySQL FULLTEXT search is good but not for large data.